# RewriteRule with two parameters on Query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Im rewritting and redirecting the URL of my current website to make it more user friendly, but Im currently having some issues with the parameters on the URL.

Basically, I want to do both a redirection and a rewriterule from this URL:

`/folder/article.php?id=val1&name=val2`

to

`/folder/val1/val2/`

I've been working with RewriteCond and RewriteRule trying to find a solution, and I've managed to create the RewriteRule so all my internal links work properly, but when I manually type the first URL, It doesnt redirect to the Clean URL version.

This is what I got:

Working RewriteRule:

`RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$   /folder/article.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]`

Now, my goal is to do a redirect so when I manually type the article.php with parameters URL, it Redirects to the clean URL.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an external rewriteRule to redirect your orignal uri to the clean version. Put the following rule before your other RewriteRules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/article.php\?id=([^&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2? [L,R]
```